# can't get data from mongodb in React

Tags: javascript, mongodb, reactjs

i have an app which loads data from mongodb to list component like this

```
React.render(<ProductsList url="http://localhost:3000/data"/>, document.getElementById('products'));
```

and then i try make a http get call to ge the data like this

```
var ProductsList = React.createClass({
  loadData: function() {
    $.ajax({
     url: this.props.url,
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(data) {
       <ProductsList url={data}/>
     },
     error: function(xhr, status, err) {
       console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
     }
   });
 },
    render: function() {
      this.loadData();
        var products = this.props.url.map(function(product) {
            return (
              <li key={product._id}>
                <Product data={product} />
              </li>
            )
        });

        return (
          <ul className="clearfix">
            {products}
          </ul>
        );
    }
});
```

but when i load the app i get this error **Uncaught TypeError: this.props.url.map is not a function** what could the problem be ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map` is not a function for strings, check the documentation for array map: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Furthermore, not related to your error, but your function `loadData` returns undefined, because you are just making the ajax call. In order to make this work, you need to use the `state` object of the react component call `this.setState()` in your success/error hooks.

Answer (score 0):

it's seems like you are not clear about the props and state of React you have to follow in below mentioned way

```
var ProductsList =React.createClass({
  getInitialState:function()
  {
    return{
      url:[]
    }
  },
  componentDidMount:function()
  {
    var that=this;
     $.ajax({
     url: 'https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos',
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(data) {
      that.setState({url:data});
     },
     error: function(xhr, status, err) {
       console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
     }
   });
  },
  ChangeContent:function()
  {
    this.setState({content:"change Content"});
  },
  render:function()
  {
     var Products = this.state.url.map(function(product) {
            return (
              <li key={product._id}>
                {product.full_name}
              </li>
            )
        });
    return(
      <div>
       {Products}
      </div>
      )
  }
});
React.render(
  <ProductsList  />,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/wIazbADP7gnlPLbDyoqQ?p=preview)